# Registering a domain name for someone else with my billing information

Tags: domains

I want to register a domain for someone using my billing information (credit card) but all the contact information are the ones of this person.

Once I get the domain, I will transfer the logins of the registrars setting page of the domain to this person, I am concerned about if the person will be able to check the billing information or even use them to purchase other domains/services.

Is there a way to buy a domain name while keeping the billing information not registered in the registrars setting page, or even buy a coupon that the person can use to register the domain name for itself.

EDIT:
I just found an interesting option on Godaddy : Moving a Domain Name out of Your Account

> You can use these instructions to move
>   a domain name from one account with us
>   to another.

Has anyone tried this before whether it just transfers the domain or the billing information too?

Comment: If you transfer access to the registrars login, they are the new owner and can do what they please. Why not have them just use their CC?

Comment: ^- just do that. i think you are looking at a headache if you use your CC with there information (the company will probably wonder if it is fraud to begin with, then if your cc is stored for any reason the other person can purchase whatever is available through the host with your credit card) i would just use there CC

Comment: They don't have a CC, that's why I am using mine

Answer (score 5):

Short answer, dont do it. You are better off helping them get it setup, using their CC for payment, and making you the administrative contact.

Comment: They have no CC, that's why I need to use mine.

Answer (score 0):

If you use your CC for registering the domains, the same card info will be automatically used by the hosting company for further billings/renewals also. There are options to change the card details at the providers end. But it is up to the one who own the domain.

So you can decide whether or not to do this. If you are confident that your friend

Comment: Your answer seems to've been cut off.